# Loading JDBC connector in Eclipse Jython plugin

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, eclipse-plugin, jython

I'm working with an Eclipse-based tool which provides an interactive Jython shell for scripting and data analysis against an internal data model.

I'm trying to write a script which exports results to some form of database, so I'm trying to use the built-in `com.ziclix.python.sql` package in Jython to provide the interface and the Xerial JDBC connector for SQLite (https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) to provide the backend.

The script below works perfectly when run outside of the third-party tool using a standard command line Jython interpreter, including relying on the `importJar()` hack which is commonly used to work around Jython not always using the user `CLASSPATH` when run using `java -jar <blah>`:

```
from com.ziclix.python.sql import zxJDBC
from java.net import URL, URLClassLoader
from java.lang import ClassLoader
from java.io import File

JDBC_URL    = "jdbc:sqlite:test.db"
JDBC_DRIVER = "org.sqlite.JDBC"
JDBC_JAR    = "E:/sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0.jar"

# Import Jar file into local class path
def importJar(jarFile):
    m = URLClassLoader.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", [URL])
    m.accessible = 1
    m.invoke(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), [File(jarFile).toURL()])

def main():
    try:
        importJar(JDBC_JAR)
        dbConn = zxJDBC.connect(JDBC_URL, None, None, JDBC_DRIVER)
        cursor = dbConn.cursor()

        # Do something useful

        cursor.close()
        dbConn.close()

    except zxJDBC.DatabaseError, msg:
        print msg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

... but fails when run from the plugin inside Eclipse, where the `zxJDBC.connect()` call errors with:

```
driver [org.sqlite.JDBC] not found
```

If I add the Jar file to the `JYTHONPATH` environment I can do `import org.sqlite.JDBC` successfully in the Python script, but the connect call still fails in the Java-side of the JDBC driver manager.

For sake of completeness the full path to the Jar file is on the `CLASSPATH`, `PYTHONPATH`, and `JYTHONPATH` environment variables ...

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect this is something to do with the OSGI framework model with per-plugin ClassLoaders, so I suspect I need to patch the current plugin class loader rather than the SystemClassLoader.

Comment: Add the jar to the `Class-Path` entry in the manifest of your JAR, or explicitly load the class using `Class.forName` to get it registered with `DriverMananger`.

Comment: It's not my tool, I'm just a user of the Jython scripting interface, so I was hoping for something I could implement purely in the Python script. I tried `Class.forName` and that doesn't work. My current workaround is to modify the tool plugin JAR file to include the JDBC connector in the and add it to the plugin Manifest's `Bundle-Classpath`, which works fine, but its not something I can reasonably expect other users of the tool to do.

Comment: In what way does `Class.forName` not work?

Comment: It throws a `ClassNotFound` exeception. It works fine in Jython outside of Eclipse, but fails when Jython is run as an Eclipse plugin (I suspect for the same reason the JDBC driver manager fails to find the class).

Comment: `Class.forName` itself has nothing to do with driver manager, it just loads the class from the class path. In the case of a JDBC driver class, that driver class then registers itself with driver manager. If it throws a `ClassNotFoundException`, that suggests the driver is not on the classpath.

Comment: That is indeed the problem. The issue is that with Eclipse OSGi modularity  it ignores the system `CLASSPATH`, and uses per-plugin loaders with a local classpath, which I have no idea how to modify at runtime ...

Comment: It is far too long ago that I have done anything with Eclipse plugins. IIRC you'll need to explicitly add the jar file to the plugins class path, but I can't recall how.

Comment: Yeah, I've managed to do that for now (see comment 5 up), which works for me, but not really something I can propose to other tool users. Oh well, thanks for trying to help - much appreciated.